# Menu icon is not working while viewing WordPress site in mobile

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Menu is not working while viewing WordPress site in mobile. When clicked on it, It will zoom out but not displaying menu.  Here is the url [www.imsamma.com](http://imsamma.com/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tried another online demo of the same template as the one you're using and I think you're missing a plugin for the mobile-menu. Either that or your theme settings aren't configure properly somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

it's showing that when I click on the menu button in mobile view ".td-menu-mob-open-menu" class is generated in body tag.

And ".sf-menu.sf-js-enabled" class give "display:block" , so that you can view the menu in mobile view.

Comment: How can i do this.can you give me a example

Comment: probably the class ".td-menu-mob-open-menu" generated from js custom file / js library file i hope, 
for ".sf-js-enabled" you can give "display:block" in js as onClick function,
because ".sf-menu" have "display:none" in your style code.